# Нет прав на редактирование файлов

Tags: php, скрипт, права

Извините за глупый вопрос, я начинающий. Например если перейти по http://1.1.1.1/skript.php, тем самыв запустив скрипт, то он не сможет редактировать файлы (любой директории). Как можно сделать, чтобы можно было редактировать файл этим скриптом? Я понял, что у пользователя нет прав. Как можно сделать, чтобы были права у любого или чтото подобное?

Comment: конкретнее скирпт сюда,на каком сервере имеется ли доступ итд

Answer (score -1):

Вы должны поставить права 777 на файл, который хотите изменять, но если вы находитесь на обычном хостинге, то другой пользователь сможет получить доступ к файлу.

Comment: Может, хоть o+x не надо?

Comment: Можно сказать понятнее для новичка?

Comment: Права на запись в файлы, а тем более на исполнение для любого пользователя давать очень чревато. Малейшая уязвимость в каком-нибудь сервисе и...  Механизм аттрибутов доступа достаточно гибкий, чтобы этого не делать. Нужного пользователя добавить в группу и всё. А то и отдать(chown) файлы пользователю сервера и 640 дать, чтобы он их без проблем читал/менял, а кому нужно мог читать имея группу.

Comment: Человек не сможет этого сделать на обычном хостинге, где у него нету прав на это. Через FTP доступно только изменить права доступа.

Comment: Хостинг с ftp сегодня - это не обычный, а мёртвый хостинг. Вы не в курсе, отсутствуют ли у автора вопроса другие возможности, ваш ответ попросту вреден. Как бы то ни было, o+w(права на запись кому угодно) скрипя зубами я согласен, но почему 777?

Comment: Дело в том, что автор попросил "Как можно сделать, чтобы были права у любого или чтото подобное?", ну, вот и ответ. У меня ещё небольшие знание прав, да сижу уже на VDS.